# How to reverse order a list? (Python 3.x)

Tags: python

How to reverse order the list containing strings where def view(self), because with reversed() I get an error that it can't be done with strings. Any help?

```
class Stack():

    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def view(self):
        for x in reversed(self.stack):
            print(self.stack[x])

    def push(self):
        item = input("Please enter the item you wish to add to the stack: ")
        self.stack.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        item = self.stack.pop(-1)
        print("You just removed item: {0}".format(item))

stack = Stack()
```

Comment: any reason you don't have simply `print(x)` in `view`?

Comment: "because with reversed() I get an error that it can't be done with strings. Any help? " No; you get an error that **indexing into** `self.stack` can't be done with strings - because `x` **is already** the string that you get by iterating in reverse. It's important to **read** and **try to understand** error messages, and to show [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message when asking about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for x in list(...):` sets x to each element of the list. You are might be confusing it with iterating over a dictionary, where x would be set to the key of each element.

```
def view(self):
    for x in reversed(self.stack):
        print(x)
```